# cURL POST request using variables

Tags: json, api, curl, post, sh

I am trying to set up a basic code to insert some customers into a our customer support software without having to go in and do each one manually.
I seem to be having issues when I introduce variables into the code.

This code works:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl https://yoursite.desk.com/api/v2/customers \
-u username:password \
-X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "first_name":"John",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "phone_numbers":
      [
        {
          "type":"Other",
          "value":"5555555555"
        }
      ],
    "emails":
      [
        {
          "type": "other",
          "value":"johndoe@email.com
        }
      ],
    "custom_fields":
      {
          "field_a":"12345"
      }
    }'
```

This code always returns the error 'invalid JSON'

```
#!/bin/sh

first=John
last=Doe
phone=5555555555
phone_type=other
email=johndoe@email.com
email_type=other
id=12345

curl https://yoursite.desk.com/api/v2/customers \
-u username:password \
-X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "first_name":'"$first"',
    "last_name":'"$last"',
    "phone_numbers":
      [
        {
          "type":'"$phone_type"',
          "value":'"$phone"'
        }
      ],
    "emails":
      [
        {
          "type":'"$email_type"',
          "value":'"$email"'
        }
      ],
    "custom_fields":
      {
          "field_a":'"$id"'
      }
    }'
```

For what it's worth, as I have been tweaking the code occasionally the error code will display "emails": "value": (invalid) and "phone_numbers":"value":(invalid)

Comment: I strongly recommend using something like `jq` to generate the JSON. That will ensure things are JSON-encoded correctly. `jq ... | curl ... -d @- ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `"$first"` is expanded to `John` (the double quotes are lost). The same goes for the other expansions. Include the required double quotes in the single quoted part of your command (but preserve the double quotes around the variable expansions):

```
#!/bin/sh

first=John
last=Doe
phone=5555555555
phone_type=other
email=johndoe@email.com
email_type=other
id=12345

curl https://yoursite.desk.com/api/v2/customers \
-u username:password \
-X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "first_name":"'"$first"'",
    "last_name":"'"$last"'",
    "phone_numbers":
      [
        {
          "type":"'"$phone_type"'",
          "value":"'"$phone"'"
        }
      ],
    "emails":
      [
        {
          "type":"'"$email_type"'",
          "value":"'"$email"'"
        }
      ],
    "custom_fields":
      {
          "field_a":"'"$id"'"
      }
    }'
```

Comment: I am learning some of the basics of this language, but I haven't come across this yet.

Comment: Why does "$first" expand to 'John'  Shouldn't $first expand to John with quotes around it?

Comment: @GradyEla For the same reason that `"John"` becomes simply `John` (it is called quote removal). If you are going to do more shell scripting, I recommend that you read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ